# NHibernate LINQ query performance, which code fragment is better?

Tags: performance, linq, fluent-nhibernate, benchmarking, queryover

This question is asking which of the two approaches below is more encouraged (and with what reasons)?

I am working with FluentNHibernate in a ServiceStack REST application using C# 4.0, but this question is general to NHibernate LINQ queries.

Is it more encouraged to:

**(Method 1)** quickly run a **simple** query which returns all rows where it matches the user's id:

```
// Query the User by id
var user = session.Get<User>(request.UserId);
```

and then separately use LINQ on the returned List to further narrow down the results:

```
// 'User' contains a 'List<Location>'
var locations = user.Locations.Where(location =>
                        location.Timestamp >= (request.MinTimestamp.HasValue ? request.MinTimestamp.Value : 0) &&
                        location.Timestamp <= (request.MaxTimestamp.HasValue ? request.MaxTimestamp.Value : DateTime.Now.ToTimestamp()));

return locations;
```

**(Method 2) or**, is it more encouraged to run a **more complicated** query which does the above in a single query:

```
var locationsQuery = session.QueryOver<LocationModel>()
                        .Where(table => table.User.Id == request.UserId)
                        .And(table => table.Timestamp >= (request.MinTimestamp.HasValue ? request.MinTimestamp.Value : 0))
                        .And(table => table.Timestamp <= (request.MaxTimestamp.HasValue ? request.MaxTimestamp.Value : DateTime.Now.ToTimestamp()));

return locationsQuery.List();
```

**if** my goals are:

a) faster execution time

---

**Benchmarks (revised)**

Revised Complete Test Code: http://pastebin.com/0ykKwcxX

**Benchmarks Output:**

**Method 1** took **147.291 seconds** over **5000 iterations**.

*Query results of the last iteration:* 
{ Timestamp=1348659703485, Latitude=179.40000, Longitude=209.40000 } 
{ Timestamp=1348659703486, Latitude=179.55000, Longitude=209.55000 } 
{ Timestamp=1348659703487, Latitude=179.70000, Longitude=209.70000 } 
{ Timestamp=1348659703488, Latitude=179.85000, Longitude=209.85000 } 
{ Timestamp=1348659703489, Latitude=180.00000, Longitude=210.00000 }

**Method 2** took **133.728 seconds** over **5000 iterations**.

*Query results of the last iteration:* 
{ Timestamp=1348659703485, Latitude=179.40000, Longitude=209.40000 } 
{ Timestamp=1348659703486, Latitude=179.55000, Longitude=209.55000 } 
{ Timestamp=1348659703487, Latitude=179.70000, Longitude=209.70000 } 
{ Timestamp=1348659703488, Latitude=179.85000, Longitude=209.85000 } 
{ Timestamp=1348659703489, Latitude=180.00000, Longitude=210.00000 }

**Difference: Method 2 was approximately 13.5 seconds faster.**

---

b) long-term re-use and stability

Comment: In terms of execution time, why don't you test it and see?

Comment: Warmup: 14.518 sec (10,000 cycles, doesn't count)
Simpler Method: 12.326 sec (10,000 cycles)
Second Method: 23.449 sec (10,000 cycles)

Comment: I'm quite surprised that the second method appeared to be slower. Have you checked the SQL queries that were executed by NHibernate? Could you please post them?

Comment: Why are you surprised? What's the concept of what you're thinking?

Comment: In the first scenario you should end up with two queries, example:
**select * from Users where UserId = <userid>**, **select * from Locations where UserId = <userid>**. In the second situation we should have only one query: **select * from Locations where UserId = <userid>**. In your measurements the second option is almost 2x slower - this is what surprises me.

Comment: What happens if you move the `DateTime.Now.Timestamp` out of the query and store it in a temp variable? Is this getting mapped and executed repeatedly in the DB? As @lowleveldesign said it would be interesting seeing the raw SQL that gets generated by NHibernate.

Comment: Same result if I move the DateTime.Now.Timestamp outside. And, I'm not sure how to see the raw SQL that gets generated by NHibernate.

Comment: `var locationsQuery = ...` isn't actually querying the database at all. `var` is `IQueryOver<LocationModel>` and not `List<LocationModel>`. Are the tests even equivalent?

Comment: I did leave out a `locationsQuery.List<LocationModel>();`, but that shouldn't matter since that makes it even longer right?

Comment: @Jason: I'm not sure. Something weird is going on if the tests that *are not* querying the database are taking longer than tests that *are*.

Comment: I've revised the test. Hopefully, this time the results are more accurate? It actually pulls values from the database this time (results of the last iteration are shown). Method 1 & Method 2 both pull identical results (which is good).

Comment: Somewhat related to the DateTime.Now.Timestamp thing, why not take that entire ?: statement out of the query and store it as a local variable? NHibernate may be generating a lot of needless sql when it converts that expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is faster execution time then I'd have thought the second approach best as it does not do an unnecessary load of the User entity. Having said that, I'm not an NHibernate user so don't know for sure, and to be certain, you should conduct some measured performance tests if it matters that much ("You can't improve what you can't measure" - can't remember who said that but it's a pretty good maxim).

Ayende has written a lot of good NHibernate posts worth looking at (e.g. http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id)

When it comes to 'long term re-use and stability' this kind of depends how you're using this code. You could always refactor the query part so that your userid and timestamp filters are extension methods. See this post for an example: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/08/30/evolutionary-project-structure/